# Phalcon PhP - how to upgrade

Tags: php, phalcon

I run phalcon php and its devtools in a macbook. My current version is 2.0.13 and I want to upgrade to version 3.

I would like to confirm (and also make a useful post to people with the same problem) if to upgrade it I just need to compile again:

```
git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
cd cphalcon/build
sudo ./install
```

Also for the devtools do I just have to follow [this guide](https://phalconphp.com/en/download/tools) again?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, just recompile with the latest build (like in your code snippet). The same goes for the devtools! Have you also noticed that phalcon is now available as a package? https://phalconphp.com/en/download

Comment: thanks @Timothy. I was asking more to be useful to other people =] And I had a problem with brew paths which I solved with this post: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3352

Comment: If you find the time, you should contribute this to the documentation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you posted exactly what you need to do in order to update your Phalcon. If you have already installed phalcon using github you can go to the same directory and make a simple `git checkout master && git pull origin master`

Sometimes `install` command doesn't work properly (doesn't recognize your `php.ini` path or picks the wrong one if you have many) and you need to update your `php.ini` with extension path manually. If newly compiled library is in different directory than it was before you need to fix it by yourself.

Phalcon is also available from linux (at least for sure on ubuntu and debian) repositories so you don't need to compile it from sources if you don't want to. [Read more here.](https://phalconphp.com/en/download)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [phalcon-switcher](https://github.com/yemexx1/phalcon-switcher). It helps to switch/upgrade from one version of phalcon to the other seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

The steps I described in my questions are the right ones to follow (I was asking to be a reference to people facing the same problem). But during the process I had some small issues and I will be adding the link to the answers that helped me solve those issues:

- [brew paths issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3352)

Also, at the end of the installation you will see this:

```
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.23/lib/php/extensions/xxxxx/
Installing header files:           /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.23/include/php/
```

You may need to update the `extension=/path/to/phalcon.so` in your php.ini. The same will happen when you run `php composer.phar install` during the phalcon devtools install. Just update the path in the files indicated.